# Why my Json data is not display in table using angular ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

[image]I want to display my Json data that return from PHP file as like this:

"{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Transaction history found.\",\"user_transactions\":[{\"user_id\":\"4\",\"amount_charged\":\"4.00\",\"amount_transferred\":\"14400.00\",\"app_rate\":\"3600.00\",\"charged_currency\":\"USD\",\"beneficiary_phone\":\"256775542757\",\"beneficiary_first_name\":\"Sapkota\",\"beneficiary_last_name\":\"Suresh\",\"beneficiary_country\":\"UG\",\"transferred_currency\":\"UGX\",\"transaction_status\":\"Delivered\",\"order_id\":\"259\",\"created_date\":\"2017-07-25 13:35:48\",\"last_modified_date\":\"2017-07-25 13:35:48\"},{\"user_id\":\"4\",\"amount_charged\":\"5.00\",\"amount_transferred\":\"18000.00\",\"app_rate\":\"3600.00\",\"charged_currency\":\"USD\",\"beneficiary_phone\":\"256775542757\",\"beneficiary_first_name\":\"Sapkota\",\"beneficiary_last_name\":\"Suresh\",\"beneficiary_country\":\"UG\",\"transferred_currency\":\"UGX\",\"transaction_status\":\"Delivered\",\"order_id\":\"258\",\"created_date\":\"2017-07-25 06:23:05\",\"last_modified_date\":\"2017-07-25 06:23:05\"}]}"

Which is fetch using Get as like:

```
    $http.get("clients.php").then(function (response) {
    $scope.response = response;
    $scope.results = JSON.parse(response.data);

    console.log($scope.results);

}
```

The problem is that, don't get any result in console .log & nothing in table row which I have write in this way. So, anybody please help me.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="result in results.user_transactions">


<td>{{ result.beneficiary_first_name}}</td>
<td>{{ result.transaction_status }}</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Your data is string. First parse it uisng using JSON.parse()

Comment: why dont you console the response? Check that first.

Comment: while console the response, I get : Object {data: ""{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Transaction histo…"last_modified_date\":\"2016-11-01 16:55:31\"}]}"", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}

Comment: @SureshSapkota what is the console for    $scope.results = JSON.parse(response.data)

Comment: I am able to parse your data. Don't know why it's not working there. Are you missing anything to add here?

Comment: Will you please update your html demo parts, so i can check my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the response as it is string.

```
$http.get("clients.php").then(function (response) {
        $scope.response = response;
        $scope.results = JSON.parse(response.data);//Parsing string to JSON

        console.log($scope.results);

    }

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="result in results.user_transaactions">

    <td>{{ res.beneficiary_first_name}}</td>//No need of using index of array
    <td>{{ res.transaction_status }}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to parse your string result to JSON using `JSON.parse()`.

```
$scope.results = JSON.parse(response.data);
```

Also there is another issue in your html

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="result in results.user_transactions">
    <td>{{ result.beneficiary_first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{ result.transaction_status }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bn7Fqdl8PrsIWwN68BHF?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi Jain, now I have got the data in consle.log after JSON.parsse() but still nothing is display in table using your code. Will you help me by checking once more.

Comment: Can you update the working demo accordingly? so that I can see where are you wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `console.log($scope.results);`?

Comment: I have attach the result png file for debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150294/discussion-between-aayushi-jain-and-suresh-sapkota).

Comment: Your data is not coming proper, are you sure what you are posting as result is the output of `console.log($scope.results);`?